# Как сравнить 2 строки типа int по значениям в БД sql server Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, codefirst

у меня есть 2 таблицы Inventory и ReceiptInvoice в них есть столбцы InventoryQuantity, и InventoryQuantityReceipt, при формировании InventoryQuantityReceipt мне нужно запретить пользователю вводить большее значение чем есть в InventoryQuantity, каким образом это сделать, использую EntityFramework Code first.

Модель инвентаря:

```
 public class Inventory
{
    [Key]
    public int InventoryNumber { get; set; }

    public int Receiptid { get; set; }

    public int Salesid { get; set; }

    public string InventoryType { get; set; }

    public int InventoryQuantity { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(1000)]
    [Index(IsUnique = true)]
    public string InventoryOfName { get; set; }

    public virtual ObservableCollection<SalesInvoice> SalesInvoices { get; set; }

    public virtual ObservableCollection<ReceiptInvoice> ReceiptInvoices { get; set; }
}
```

Модель расхода:

```
public class ReceiptInvoice
{

    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [ConcurrencyCheck]
    [Column("Дата")]
    public DateTime DateOfArrivalReceipt { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [ConcurrencyCheck]
    [Column("Номер Инвентаря")]
    public int InventoryNumberReceipt { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [ConcurrencyCheck]
    [Column("Количество Инвентаря")]
    public int InventoryQuantityReceipt { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [ConcurrencyCheck]
    [Column("Id Сотрудника")]
    public int EmployeeIdReceipt { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [ConcurrencyCheck]
    [Column("Id Склада")]
    public int WarehouseIdReceipt { get; set; }

    public SalesInvoice SalesInvoices { get; set; }

    public Inventory Inventory { get; set; }

    public Employee Employee { get; set; }

    public Warehouse Warehouse { get; set; }
}
```

Контекст:

```
public class CompanyDataContext : DbContext
{
    public CompanyDataContext()
        : base("name=CompanyData")
    {

    }
    public DbSet<ReceiptInvoice> ReceiptInvoices { get; set; }
    public DbSet<SalesInvoice> SalesInvoices { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Inventory> Inventories { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Warehouse> Warehouses { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        //отношение 1 ко многим Inventory и ReceiptInvoice
        modelBuilder.Entity<ReceiptInvoice>()
        .HasRequired<Inventory>(s => s.Inventory)
         .WithMany(g => g.ReceiptInvoices)
        .HasForeignKey<int>(s => s.InventoryNumberReceipt);

        //отношение 1 ко многим Employee и ReceiptInvoice
        modelBuilder.Entity<ReceiptInvoice>()
        .HasRequired<Employee>(s => s.Employee)
         .WithMany(g => g.ReceiptInvoices)
        .HasForeignKey<int>(s => s.EmployeeIdReceipt);

        //отношение 1 ко многим Warehouse и ReceiptInvoice
        modelBuilder.Entity<ReceiptInvoice>()
        .HasRequired<Warehouse>(s => s.Warehouse)
         .WithMany(g => g.ReceiptInvoices)
        .HasForeignKey<int>(s => s.WarehouseIdReceipt);

        //отношение 1 ко многим Inventory и SalesInvoice
        modelBuilder.Entity<SalesInvoice>()
        .HasRequired<Inventory>(s => s.Inventory)
         .WithMany(g => g.SalesInvoices)
        .HasForeignKey<int>(s => s.InventoryNumberSales);

        //отношение 1 ко многим Employee и SalesInvoice
        modelBuilder.Entity<SalesInvoice>()
        .HasRequired<Employee>(s => s.Employee)
         .WithMany(g => g.SalesInvoices)
        .HasForeignKey<int>(s => s.EmployeeIdSales);

        //отношение 1 ко многим Warehouse и SalesInvoice
        modelBuilder.Entity<SalesInvoice>()
        .HasRequired<Warehouse>(s => s.Warehouse)
         .WithMany(g => g.SalesInvoices)
        .HasForeignKey<int>(s => s.WarehouseIdSales);

        //отношение 1 к 1 SalesInvoice и ReceiptInvoice
        modelBuilder.Entity<ReceiptInvoice>()
        .HasRequired(c => c.SalesInvoices)
        .WithRequiredPrincipal(c => c.ReceiptInvoices);
    }
}
```

Попробовал так наговнокодить добавление Карточки расхода, но в InventoryQuantity возвращает 0

```
 using (CompanyDataContext db = new CompanyDataContext())
        {
            try
            {
                SalesInvoice sales = new SalesInvoice();
                Inventory inventory = new Inventory();

                int inventoryQuantity = Convert.ToInt32(TextBoxInventoryQuantity.Text);
                if (inventoryQuantity <= inventory.InventoryQuantity)
                {
                    sales.InventoryQuantitySales = inventoryQuantity;
                    sales.Id = Convert.ToInt32(TextBoxID.Text);
                    sales.DateOfArrivalSales = DateTime.Now.Date;
                    sales.EmployeeIdSales = Convert.ToInt32(TextBoxEmployeeId.Text);
                    sales.InventoryNumberSales = Convert.ToInt32(TextBoxInventoryNumber.Text);
                    sales.WarehouseIdSales = Convert.ToInt32(TextBoxWarehouseId.Text);
                    db.SalesInvoices.Add(sales);
                    db.SaveChanges();
                    gridDataExpense.ItemsSource = db.SalesInvoices.ToList();
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Вы не можете взять больше инвентаря чем было изначально");
                }
            }
            catch (FormatException exeption)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(exeption.Message);
            }
            catch(System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Данные расхода не соответствуют данным прихода");
            }

            gridDataExpense.ItemsSource = db.SalesInvoices.ToList();
        }
```

Comment: Корень ваших проблем в том, что вы пишите лапшекод: у вас в одном месте сплелись воедино абсолютно разные слои приложения: и UI (судя по MessageBox) и Persistence (судя по DB) и Application (судя по логике). Могу порекомендовать разнести толково по слоям, думаю, вам понравится, когда у объекты будут инстанцироваться через фабрики, отдельно будет проверка бизнес-правил и потом только будет сохранение в базу.

Comment: Мне и самому не нравиться то что я написал, проблема в том что мне нужно сдать эту работу в ближайшие сроки, потом думаю полностью всё переделать

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Судя по всему вы испытываете проблемы от того, что не читаете из базы инвентарь, а создаёте пустой вот тут: `Inventory inventory = new Inventory();` - ведь там же все int поля будут ноль, а строки null. Ну и чего вы тогда в `if (inventoryQuantity <= inventory.InventoryQuantity)` будете всегда с `<= 0` сравнивать, логично?

Смотрите, самый тривиальный код, минимальный пример для воспроизведения:

```
void Main()
{
    Inventory inventory = new Inventory();
    Console.WriteLine(inventory.InventoryQuantity);
}

// Define other methods and classes here

public class Inventory
{
    public int InventoryNumber { get; set; }

    public int Receiptid { get; set; }

    public int Salesid { get; set; }

    public string InventoryType { get; set; }

    public int InventoryQuantity { get; set; }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Проблема не имеет пока отношения у EF.

Вам надо прочитать inventory из базы, этого в коде нет.

Comment: Спасибо, я напрямую обратился к бд и сделал выборку `int inventoryQuantity = Convert.ToInt32(TextBoxInventoryQuantity.Text);
                    var inventory = db.Inventories.All(c => c.InventoryQuantity <= inventoryQuantity);
                    if (inventory)`